# copy a complete XML tree except for some branches based on a criteria

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having a list of parts which could contain parts themselves. Actually a bill of material (BOM). Some of the parts have an element which identifies them as "spare parts". When doing my transformation into another XML-file, I am only interested in the nodes (and ancestors) which contain "spare parts", in other words `<Spare_part_indicator>` but maintain all the siblings in that particular node as well.
Here my sample BOM as XML:

```
    <Level levelNo="1">
        <Component_number>HEKT109476R4</Component_number>
        <Object_description>KEY INTERLOCK</Object_description>
        <Level levelNo="2">
            <Component_number>HENS434350</Component_number>
            <Object_description>LOCK BARREL (PLACEHOLDER)</Object_description>
        </Level>
        <Level levelNo="2">
            <Component_number>HEKT460536P3</Component_number>
            <Object_description>SWITCH_SEC:_PSEN ME1S/1AR_2O/2S</Object_description>
            <Spare_part_indicator>2</Spare_part_indicator>
            <Sort_String>S420</Sort_String>
            <QR_code>HEKT460536P3.png</QR_code>
        </Level>
        <Level levelNo="2">
            <Component_number>HEKT460751R2</Component_number>
            <Object_description>SHEET METAL</Object_description>
            <Level levelNo="3">
                <Component_number>HEKT323873P1</Component_number>
                <Object_description>C-PAN</Object_description>
            </Level>
            <Level levelNo="3">
                <Component_number>HEKT453450P5</Component_number>
                <Object_description>HIGH VOLTAGE CAPACITOR 5NF/30KV 10%</Object_description>
                <Spare_part_indicator>3</Spare_part_indicator>
                <QR_code>HEKT453450P5.png</QR_code>
            </Level>
        </Level>
    </Level>
    <Level levelNo="1">
        <Component_number>HEKT109444R3</Component_number>
        <Object_description>FILTER NETWORK 500KW</Object_description>
        <Level levelNo="2">
            <Component_number>HEKT457790P1</Component_number>
            <Object_description>BRACKET</Object_description>
        </Level>
        <Level levelNo="2">
            <Component_number>HEKT323840P1</Component_number>
            <Object_description>COIL</Object_description>
            <Spare_part_indicator>3</Spare_part_indicator>
            <Sort_String>L401</Sort_String>
            <QR_code>HEKT323840P1.png</QR_code>
        </Level>
    </Level>
```

Now I want to transform the list above into a new XML tree containing only the nodes with the element `<Spare_part_indicator>` but maintaining the hierarchy, including the ancestors. I came across the following XSL stylesheet which, after some modification, did exactly what i wanted. But unfortunately it only leaves me the element `<Spare_part_indicator>` and removes all the other elements, like `Component_number`etc.

```
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="subSelectionXPath"
  select="//Spare_part_indicator"
  />

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=
   "descendant::node()
        [count(.|$subSelectionXPath)
        =
         count($subSelectionXPath)
        ]
   ">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:when>

   <xsl:when test=
   "count(.|$subSelectionXPath)
   =
    count($subSelectionXPath)
   ">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected outcome of the BOM above shall look like this:

```
<Level levelNo="1">
    <Component_number>HEKT109476R4</Component_number>
    <Object_description>KEY INTERLOCK</Object_description>
    <Level levelNo="2">
        <Component_number>HEKT460536P3</Component_number>
        <Object_description>SWITCH_SEC:_PSEN ME1S/1AR_2O/2S</Object_description>
        <Spare_part_indicator>2</Spare_part_indicator>
        <Sort_String>S420</Sort_String>
        <QR_code>HEKT460536P3.png</QR_code>
    </Level>
    <Level levelNo="2">
        <Component_number>HEKT460751R2</Component_number>
        <Object_description>SHEET METAL</Object_description>
        <Level levelNo="3">
            <Component_number>HEKT453450P5</Component_number>
            <Object_description>HIGH VOLTAGE CAPACITOR 5NF/30KV 10%</Object_description>
            <Spare_part_indicator>3</Spare_part_indicator>
            <QR_code>HEKT453450P5.png</QR_code>
        </Level>
    </Level>
</Level>
<Level levelNo="1">
    <Component_number>HEKT109444R3</Component_number>
    <Object_description>FILTER NETWORK 500KW</Object_description>
    <Level levelNo="2">
        <Component_number>HEKT323840P1</Component_number>
        <Object_description>COIL</Object_description>
        <Spare_part_indicator>3</Spare_part_indicator>
        <Sort_String>L401</Sort_String>
        <QR_code>HEKT323840P1.png</QR_code>
    </Level>
</Level>
```

I could not figure out so far, how I can also keep the sibling elements, as well as the elements in the parent nodes and a hint here and there would be very much appreciated.
I hope I could describe the problem properly and please be patient with me since I only started to discover the power of XSL stlyesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- except levels without Spare_part_indicator anywhere inside -->
  <xsl:template match="Level[not(.//Spare_part_indicator)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what a quick response! exactly what I wanted to achieve

Comment: XSLT is declarative and it's important to thoroughly understand what do you want to achieve instead of starting to think about the ways how to do it. As you can see, solution is very simple and very "declarative".

Comment: Indeed the solution is simple and, as you call it "declarative". One question I still would like to ask. The resulting xml document contains white spaces (line breaks) for the ignored nodes. Just curious how that can be avoided within the same style sheet? Not that it would be a problem, since the following XSL-FO transformation does not care about it. I am just curious. Thanks

Comment: Add <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> below xsl:output

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually it was what I did before I asked, but guess I had done something wrong and Xalan aborted the translation. Now it works fine. I appreciate your help very much